# Ver mi web desde otra red exterior

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, servidor, apache2

estoy configurando apache2 en ubuntu 16 para ver mi web desde el exterior. Ante todo nada profesional solo para un trabajo personal. Bueno parte del trabajo esta hecho, la web se ve tanto local como desde el exterior incluso con una redirección de un dominio NO-IP al puerto 8080. Vamos que tanto poniendo mi IP publica como el dominio NO-IP se ve.
EL problema es que se ve la pared de directorios no el index.html. Supongo que me explico en esto por que aquí tengo el problema. Cuando entras en el dominio o poniendo la IP publica sale los directorios y no aparece directamente el index.php.
Os pongo los archivos de configuración:
1º El virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName prueba.ddns.net
ServerAlias www.prueba.ddns.net
DocumentRoot /var/www/prueba
```

Hace años yo ya lo tenia bien configurado y se que a este archivo hay que añadir unas directivas, estoy seguro que aqui hay que añadirlas pero ya no me acuerdo.

Bueno el problema es que yo quiero que al poner mi IP o dominio no IP aparezca la web, no la pared de directorios. He mirado y en la documentación dice que si vas a apache2.conf y modificas :

```
 <Directory /var/www>
    Options **Indexes**  FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

a:

```
    <Directory /var/www>
    Options **-Indexes**  FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
   </Directory>
```

se debería solucionar el problema, pero entonces me aparece el famoso mensaje forbidden 403.
Yo creo que hay que poner una directiva en el virtualhost para que acceda directamente al index.php.
También modifique los permisos de /var/www a 755 os pongo los permisos:

```
introducir el código aquí
    drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 oct  1 20:43 .
    drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 sep 25 12:02 ..
    drwxrwsr-x 16 root root 4096 oct  1 20:43 Prueba
```

Bueno como digo no es para nada profesional, osea la seguridad y demás me da igual.
A ver si me podéis decir algo.